# How to resolve a name collision between a C++ namespace and a global function?

Tags: c++, namespaces, name-conflict

if I define a namespace `log` somewhere and make it accessible in the global scope, this will clash with `double log(double)` from the standard `cmath` header. Actually, most compilers seem to go along with it -- most versions of SunCC, MSVC, GCC -- but GCC 4.1.2 doesn't.

Unfortunately, there seems no way to resolve the ambiguity, as `using` declarations are not legal for namespace identifiers. Do you know any way I could write `log::Log` in the global namespace even if `cmath` is included?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Would anybody know what the C++03 standard has to say about this? I would have thought that the scope operator sufficiently disambiguates the use of `log` in the code example below.

```
#include <cmath>

namespace foo
{

namespace log
{

struct Log { };

} // namespace log

} // namespace foo


using namespace foo;

int main()
{
    log::Log x;

    return 0;
}

// g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)

// log.cpp: In function `int main()':
// log.cpp:20: error: reference to `log' is ambiguous
// /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:110: error: candidates are: double log(double)
//     log.cpp:7: error:                 namespace foo::log { }
// log.cpp:20: error: expected `;' before `x'
```

Comment: Why not just write it as `foo::log::Log` to prevent the ambiguousity?

Comment: `Log` is not the only member of `foo::log`, there are lots of these. But yes, I'll probably end up fully qualifying all of these if there is no other way.

Comment: @cj: You might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136).

Comment: Shouldn't C identifiers imported through the `<c****>` versions of C standard headers be located in the `std` namespace? Is it a v4.1 implementation bug (in g++ 4.4 this code works fine) or I remember this thing wrong?

Comment: @Matteo Italia: These identifiers are required to be also accessible in the global namespace. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524139/ansi-c-functions-namespace-in-iso-c/1524387#1524387 .

Comment: @cj: as far as I understand from those standard quotations, as far as the standard is concerned these identifiers have to be put in the global namespace only if you include the `<name.h>` C header, while including `<cname>` should put them only in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @Matteo: you're right, I misread.

Comment: I found this bug to be very annoying, I could patch `/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h` but then the file `<cmath>` expects `log` for example to be in the global namespace (see line 356 in gcc's stdlib `<cmath>`, it reads `using ::log;`. I wonder if one can play with all the defined macros in order to correct all this behavior. By the way, @MatteoItalia, I find this also in gcc 4.7, so if it was fixed in 4.4 the bug came back.

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest:

```
foo::log::Log x; // Your logging class
::log(0.0); // Log function
```

Generally I wouldn't write `using namespace foo;` as there is no point having it in the `foo` namespace if you're not going to use it and it pollutes the global namespace.

See this related question:
[How do you properly use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c/41598)

Answer (score 9):

Although it does not help you, the error from GCC 4.1.2 is incorrect. The `log` in `log::Log` can only refer to a class or namespace name.

If your code also needs to compile with GCC 4.1.2, then there are two options:

1. Use the fully qualified name `foo::log::Log`
2. Use a namespace alias:

```
    namespace log1 = foo::log;
    log1::Log logger;
```

Comment: +1 for the idea of using an alias. Are you sure the error is incorrect? I presume you mean that the scope operator resolves the ambiguity because it cannot be applied to a function name? I'm not sure what the standard says about this special case. But regarding namespace definitions, see section 7.3.1: "The identifier in an original-namespace-definition shall not have been previously defined in the declarative region in which the original-namespace-definition appears."

Comment: I am sure the error is incorrect. I had to look it up in the standard, and according to the grammar only a class or namespace name can occur before the scope operator. The declaration of your `log` namespace is not a problem, because it is not being defined in the same namespace as the `log` function. (namespace is withing `foo` namespace, function is in global namespace)

Answer (score 1):

`cmath` uses `::log` for some reason to get it from the global scope and can't decide between the function and your namespace.

Namespaces keep code contained to prevent [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892976/why-is-my-log-in-the-std-namespace) and [pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) of function signatures.

[Here](http://ideone.com/vSU5tD)'s a complete and documented demo of [proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace) [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c) usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>  // Uses ::log, which would be the log() here if it were not in a namespace, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892976/why-is-my-log-in-the-std-namespace

// Silently overrides std::log
//double log(double d) { return 420; }

namespace uniquename {
    using namespace std;  // So we don't have to waste space on std:: when not needed.

    double log(double d) {
        return 42;
    }

    int main() {
        cout << "Our log: " << log(4.2) << endl;
        cout << "Standard log: " << std::log(4.2);
        return 0;
    }
}

// Global wrapper for our contained code.
int main() {
    return uniquename::main();
}
```

Output:

```
Our log: 42
Standard log: 1.43508
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++0x or c++11, the following should work, compile with -std=c++0x or -std=c++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

namespace ___ {
namespace log {

void init() {
    std::cout << "log::init()" << std::endl;
}

} // namespace log
} // namespace ___

using namespace ___;

int main() {
    log::init();
    std::cout << ::log(3.2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```