# Why is my log in the std namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading

In the code below, I define a trivial `log` function. In `main` I try *not* to call it; I call `std::log`. Nevertheless, my own `log` is called; and I see "log!" on screen. Does anyone know why? I use G++ 4.7 and clang++ 3.2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double log(const double x) { std::cout << "log!\n"; return x; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::log(3.14);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like a serious compiler bug...

Comment: I can reproduce this on g++ 4.6 under Macports. It does not happen in g++ 4.2 or 4.4, though.

Comment: http://codepad.org/Uwhgrv7q http://codepad.org/z07Ctfyn Frome these two i would say that the std::log() function calls log() . but then it should generate an error/warning that your file redefines log or something like t

Comment: This is interesting. I can reproduce this even on ideone... http://ideone.com/wSPVF

I'd like to know the answer to this myself.

Comment: i tried the same in ideone - if you comment out the new log function it calls the mathematic log function

Comment: @ColeJohnson: It's why you use *namespaces*. Not everything needs to be in a class. Personally, I put everything in a namespace except `main`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

C++ Standard 17.6.1.2 paragraph 4 (emphasis mine):

> Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of each header `cname` shall be the same as that of the corresponding header `name.h`, as specified in the C Standard library (1.2) or the C Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion.  In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std`.  **It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace `std` by explicit *using-declarations* (7.3.3).**

g++ does it the latter way so that some of the same header files can be reused for C and C++.  So g++ is allowed to declare and define `double log(double)` in the global namespace.

Section 17.6.4.3.3 paragraphs 3 and 4:

> Each name from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with `extern "C"` linkage, both in namespace `std` and in the global namespace.
>
> Each function signature from the Standard C library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"`linkage, or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

And up at the top of Section 17.6.4.3 paragraph 2:

> If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.

You, on the other hand, may *not* declare or define `::log` in any way.

It's too bad the g++ toolchain doesn't give you any error messages, though.

Comment: By "C++ Standard" I presume you mean the C++11 standard (N3337); the symbolic name for 17.6.1.2 is `[headers]`, and 17.6.4.3  is `[reserved.names]`

Answer (score 9):

What happens, I expect, is that `std::log` simply delegates to `::log`. Unfortunately, `::log` only provides a `float` overload, and you kindly provide a `double` overload, making yours a better match. But I still don't see how it even gets considered in the overload set.

Comment: `<cmath>` is required to provide `log(double)`.

Comment: I expected the same on MSVC10 and I _eventually_ did get a duplicate symbol error on link but only after 3 or 4 rebuilds.

Comment: @aschepler: `<cmath>` is required to provide `double std::log(double)` (I'm making the focus on namespace a big deal, because it is right now). The standard requires them to be in the `::std` namespace, and each implementation is free to define them in the global namespace if they so choose.

Comment: @DeadMG: Don't you mean `::log` (the C library function) provides a `double` parameter type? It's `::logf` that provides the `float` type.

Answer (score 9):

On libstdc++'s `cmath` you will see this:

```
using ::log;
```

So it's bringing in the math.h functions from the global namespace into `std`. Unfortunately you are supplying an implementation for `double log(double)`, so the linker will not use the one from the math lib. <strike>So definitely a bug in libstdc++</strike>.

EDIT: I claim it's a bug in libstdc++ because `std::log` should not suffer from interferences with the C library when you are explicitly asking for the `std::` versions. Of course, this way to override standard library functions is an old "feature" from the C language.

EDIT 2: I found out that the standard doesn't actually forbid bringing names from the global namespace into `std`. So not a bug after all, only a consequence of the implementation details.

Comment: The `using` declaration should only import the declarations that are visible at that point, I think, which would mean that a later declared function should not get imported this way.

Comment: I edited my answer, the standard allows for this kind of implementation, that first declares the math.h functions, then brings the `double` versions into `std`.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, the compiler is free to implement the C library in the global namespace and delegate to it (this is implementation defined).

> 17.6.1.2.4 Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of each header cname shall be the same
>   as that of the corresponding header name.h, as speciﬁed in the C standard library (1.2) or the C Unicode
>   TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for
>   names which are deﬁned as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std. **It is
>   unspeciﬁed whether these names are ﬁrst declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected
>   into namespace std by explicit using-declarations** (7.3.3).

In general, I'd avoid making a function with the same signature as one of the C standard library's. The C++ standard certainly gives compilers the freedom to be using these signatures if it so chooses, which means you may be fighting your compiler if you try to use the same signatures. Hence, you get weird results.

I would expect a linker error or warning though, and I think it may be worth reporting this.

[edit]

Wow, ninja'd.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've overridden it in the global namespace. Using a namespace avoids that danger if you don't want to move on to a safer, cleaner language like [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/) for example.

[Proper use of namespace demo](http://ideone.com/vSU5tD):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>  // Uses ::log, which would be the log() here if it were not in a namespace, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892976/why-is-my-log-in-the-std-namespace

// Silently overrides std::log
//double log(double d) { return 420; }

namespace uniquename {
    using namespace std;  // So we don't have to waste space on std:: when not needed.

    double log(double d) {
        return 42;
    }

    int main() {
        cout << "Our log: " << log(4.2) << endl;
        cout << "Standard log: " << std::log(4.2);
        return 0;
    }
}

// Global wrapper for our contained code.
int main() {
    return uniquename::main();
}
```

Output:

```
Our log: 42
Standard log: 1.43508
```